# Intermittent coloured bands on Apple Cinema Display A1082

Tags: mac, hardware, screen, color, cinema-display

Recently I acquired a 23" Apple Cinema Display (A1082). After sourcing a power brick I connected it to my 2013 MacPro tower and -- it worked. Great clarity, looked good apart from the broad bands of color appearing at random intervals across the screen (top to bottom). I've managed to disassemble the monitor to check for anything amiss inside and the inside looks fine. One thing that does puzzle me is the wires for the smaller 'power panel' connecter are taped to the chassis -- not sure why as they do have a connector plug fitted...

Is this unit salvageable? Has anybody had experience with this kind of problem?

Looks pretty good I think...

[image]

Why is this plug taped to the chassis?

[image]

Comment: Have you tested with a different computer? Because have you considered it could be the graphics / memory on the computer and not a fault with the display?

Comment: Seeing that this model was introduced in 2004, it is rather long in the tooth and several components may be past their useful shelf life. It is also possible that the DVI cable/adapter is at fault. As for the taped plug, it's hard to see exactly where this goes. Usually, cables are taped in place by Apple to prevent damage during assembly/disassembly, but this looks a little sketchy, as if it was added later. I used to have one of these displays, but it gave up the ghost with an astounding visual extravaganza of colors and flashes.

Comment: @Solar Mike -- currently using another monitor on the computer I intended to use this monitor on without any problems. Video card is less than a year old so no probs in that department!

Comment: @IconDaemon -- I'm aware this is an old monitor -- just trying to ensure that it's really 'on its way out' before I trash it. Shame because I've hankered after an Apple monitor for years... great size (bigger than the one I'm using) and it ALMOST works perfectly (apart from the lines of course). And, of course, it looks 'insanely cool'... ; ) 

There's actually a corresponding plug for the one taped to chassis inside the casing...